# PHP Image Upload using POST

Tags: php, linux, apache, configuration, server

I am trying to do a simple image uploader. I have searched for hours now and I made sure to set the enctype and I also changed my php.ini according to what I wanna do. The permissions of the files and folders are also correct. I've tried the exact same code on another webserver and it's working. I am running **apache2 with php5 on a raspberry pi**.

*HTML Code*

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="file" name="uimage"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
    </table>    
</form>
```

*PHP Code*

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

The PHP Code returns an empty array. `var_dump($_POST);` works fine. On the other server both are working and the image uploads successfully. I assume it has to do with my server. I've checked the *php.ini* file and the *000-default* in sites-enabled but really can not figure out what causes the issue.

This is what the *error.log* from apache2 says:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uimage in /var/www/dmz/dotpic/upload.php on line 48, referer:
>   http://localhost/upload.php

**Edit:**

By "POST" in the title of the question I mean the form method I am using. I am not trying to access the image using the `$_POST` array. Sorry for that.

Comment: can we see what upload.php looks like

Comment: I think this would be too much for a comment. My code is working fine on another server as mentioned above so I'm pretty sure it's not causing the error. Since the array `$_FILES` is empty on my server I'm sure the rest of the code doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

use `$_FILES['uimage']` to access your file, $_POST does not work for files.
more info use this link:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: How come you think I've used $_POST? I am using this: `$image = $_FILES["uimage"]["name"];`

Comment: then why did you not put it in your question, and it was just a suggestion to you

Comment: I've put it in my question, even used the code block markdown. Not meant to be offending!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$_POST` to get files, you should use `$_FILES['uimage']` to get the uploaded file.

`$_FILES['uimage']` is an array with some information about size, temp name of the uploaded file, upload result and file type of the uploaded file.

Comment: I know, that's why I tried to dump it using `var_dump()` for `$_FILE` and not `$_POST` as I said in my question. I am using this code to get the image: `$image = $_FILES["uimage"]["name"];`

Answer (score 0):

As what had been already answered above. You should use $_FILES['uimage'] and not $_POST['uimage']. Good Luck. :)

Comment: Thanks! I am using this: `$image = $_FILES["uimage"]["name"];` I've also wrote `$_FILES` in my question. I don't know why you think I used $_POST.

Comment: Oops. HAHAHA. I was just pre assuming everything. Sorry about that. But honestly that would be the most common error. Even I do that oftentimes. :) Sorry Again. @angeloid

Comment: It's okay, didn't meant to be offending! The most common error, at least from what I saw using google and the search here, regarding this topic is to forget to set the enctype to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Yeah, That's one of the most common too. :) @angeloid